# How can I format or normalize a wikipedia title in order to get its wikipedia page id (python)

Tags: python, wikipedia

## Introduction

As input we have a wikipedia page `title` for which we want to extract its wikipedia `page ID`. For this purpose i am using the following python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

import requests

if __name__ == "__main__": 
   url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Daniel cudmore businessman"
   result = requests.get(url).json()
   print result
```

---

### Problem

I **can't** find the wikipedia page ids of the following titles:

[1- daniel cudmore businessman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Cudmore_%28businessman%29)

```
{u'batchcomplete': u'', u'query': {u'pages': {u'-1': {u'ns': 0, u'missing': u'', u'title': u'Daniel cudmore businessman'}}}}
```

The actual id of the page should be: **​37030093**

In here the problem is that the used wikipedia page title is **Daniel Cudmore (businessman)** where as mine has the following form **daniel cudmore businessman**.

---

[2- Prince david of georgia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_David_of_Georgia):

```
{u'batchcomplete': u'', u'query': {u'normalized': [{u'to': u'Prince david of georgia', u'from': u'prince david of georgia'}], u'pages': {u'-1': {u'ns': 0, u'missing': u'', u'title': u'Prince david of georgia'}}}}
```

The actual id of the page should be: **3443932**

In here the title of the wikipedia page and the title that I used are the same. I can't find the problem.

---

On the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql):

```sql
SELECT ?id WHERE { 
     <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Daniel_Cudmore_(businessman)>  
     <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fid%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FDaniel_Cudmore_%28businessman%29%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageID%3E%20%3Fid%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: You may be able to do this with a very simple sparql query to dbpedia.

Comment: I was really thinking about it @JoshuaTaylor. The queries are actually:

`<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Daniel_Cudmore_(businessman)>` . it's a lot faster as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latter example ("Prince_david_of_georgia"), you've got different character cases (compare with "Prince_David_of_Georgia"), so that particular page doesn't exist either, on Wikipedia

You could use the `Special Search`-URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search/Prince_david_of_georgia to get the requested page and then retrieve the ID

or a list of suggestions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search/Daniel_Cudmore_businessman
Which you can parse for the first entry. This will likely be your page. Do some string comparison without white space, braces etc to double check - then retrieve the ID as you did, already.

Comment: I wanted to do a google search. retrieve the first 10 results then search for a wikipedia page. Your suggestion is ok. Instead of going through the whole process of google queries

Comment: yes, that's an alternative, a google search like `inurl:wikipedia.org Prince david of georgia`